# How to declare global variable in order to kill second EXCEL.EXE from Task Manager

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

Following code opens two EXCEL.EXE in the Task Manager.

I want to kill second opening EXCEL.EXE from the Task Manager when Form1 is closing.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Kill all EXCEL.EXE process from Task Manager
    For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        prog.Kill()
    Next

    Dim FirstxlApp As New Excel.Application 'Open first EXCEL.EXE in the Task Manager

    Dim datestart As Date = Date.Now
    Dim SecondxlApp As New Excel.Application 'Open second EXCEL.EXE in the Task Manager
    Dim dateEnd As Date = Date.Now

    SecondxlApp.Visible = True

    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    wb1 = SecondxlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim xlp() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    For Each Process As Process In xlp
        If Process.StartTime >= datestart And Process.StartTime <= dateEnd Then
            Process.Kill()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

How to declare global variable in order to solve following errors?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables `dateEnd` and `dateStart` are hidden to `FormClosing` method as they are only declared within the `Form_Load` method.

Change your code to:

`Public Class Form1
    Dim dateEnd, dateStart As DateTime
 Private Sub Form_load`

Then they will be accessable to all methods with the form.